# JTable with JComboBox navigation and selection using keyboard only

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I'd like to navigate on JTable using only a keyboard, and select values from JComboBox cells also only with a keyboard.

I'm using Oracle Java JTable tutorial, the code is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableRenderDemoProject/src/components/TableRenderDemo.java

[image: table]

My question is how to select items from combo box when navigating only with the keyboard, for example:

1. I execute the mentioned demo, the table initially is out of focus
2. I press 'tab' on the keyboard and the table receives focus, selects the first row and the leftmost column, then pressing 'tab' twice the focus moves to 'Sport' column which has JComboBox as cell editor
3. Here is what I want to achieve: while focus is on 'Sport' column, I'd like to press for example 'r' letter on the keyboard to change a value for Kathy's sport to 'Rowing' (which is in the list). But the only thing happens when I press 'r' while on that cell is the cell renderer changes to JComboBox, but does not select any desired value from it despite I continue to press various keys on the keyboard.

[image: JComboBox appears]

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: assuming you want to select a cell (in the same column, or another - doesn't really matter, the only difference is looping range) with content matching some condition related to the letter typed: implement a keyListener, let it loop across the values of the cells, when it finds fitting content select the cell containing that content.

Comment: a potential hurdle might be that the string representation of the cell content != content.toString (which is the default): then you need some means to get hold of string representation (good ol' SwingX has support for such mapping but is .. no longer maintained ;)

Comment: thanks @kleopatra but it seems I wasn't specific enough. updated my question. I want to change the value of the JComboBox by pressing keyboard keys and not to use a mouse at all when working with JTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling I found what I think I needed, here is a link to thread and example from oracle.com [oracle.com](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1350085/jcombobox-keyboard-navigation)

Basically a custom ComboBoxEditor which extends DefaultCellEditor solves the issues. Looks like the default one has several bugs.